# A differentiation with first principles question for two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I know this question is probably quite easy but it's been some time since I've done any sort of calculus and since a google search failed to turn up anything relevant to this specific question I thought I should ask it here. I know that for first principles differentiation for one variable we have to have the following:

$du = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(a+h)- u(a)}{h}$

However, for two variables, what do I have to divide $u(t + dt, S + \mu ds) - u(t,s)$ by in order to obtain $du$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused, but I think you're looking for the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) or [total differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$If $u$ is a (differentiable) function of two real variables, then loosely, "$du$" isn't a number, but an *ordered pair of numbers*
$$
\frac{\dd u}{\dd t}(t, s) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{u(t + h, s) - u(t, s)}{h},\qquad
\frac{\dd u}{\dd s}(t, s) = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{u(t, s + k) - u(t, s)}{k}.
$$
Technically, at each point $(t, s)$, the derivative is a real-valued linear function of two variables:
$$
\bigl(du(t, s)\bigr)(h, k)
  = h\, \frac{\dd u}{\dd t}(t, s) + k\, \frac{\dd u}{\dd s}(t, s).
$$
(Parse this carefully: The *single symbol* "$\bigl(du(t, s)\bigr)$" is the name of a linear function, whose input variables are $(h, k)$, and whose output value is the expression on the right.)

Comment: Thanks for that, that's what I figured. I just have one more follow up question: Say for instance I only care about moving in the '$s$' direction and that the '$t$' direction does not matter. If I were to now write: $du = \lim_{\mu ds \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(t+dt, s + \mu ds) - u(t,s)}{\mu ds}$ would that be correct? I mean I know it's not written the same as the equations you've given above, but since $t$ is irrelevant then can I do this?

Comment: Moving only in the $s$ direction is tantamount to taking $k = 0$. The limit expression you write is the coefficient of $h$ in $$u(t, s + h) \approx u(t, s) + du(t, s)(h, 0) = u(t, s) + h\, \frac{\dd u}{\dd s}(t, s).$$(Incidentally, I used $k$ in two distinct roles: As a dummy variable in a limit, and as a _bona fide_ variable in the differential. To say "$k = 0$" means taking $k$ in the latter role.)

Comment: Ah ok sorry I guess what I meant to say was I want to move in the '$t$' direction since I want to keep the expression I have above. In that case would the expression above be correct? Sorry if these are really dumb question, I'm from more of a stats background and even though these seem trivial to me I'm still not 100% sure on this stuff

Comment: In the expression$$\frac{u(t + dt, s + \mu\, ds) - u(t, s)}{\text{something}},$$"both variables vary", so if you're trying to evaluate a rate of change, you need _both_ $dt \to 0$ and $\mu\, ds \to 0$. It's possible you want a [_directional derivative_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), in which $dt$ and $\mu\, ds$ are proportional as they tend to $0$...? That would look something like$$\lim_{ds \to 0} \frac{u(t + \lambda\, ds, s + \mu\, ds) - u(t, s)}{\sqrt{\lambda^{2} + \mu^{2}}\, ds}$$[sic] $\lambda\, ds$ in the $t$ slot.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, this clears up pretty much all the questions I had :)